# How to use push() or pop() on js array in kotlin?

Tags: javascript, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I have a JavaScript Object:

```
{
   keyA: "ValueA",
   keyB: ["a", "b", "c"]
}
```

How to define it in Kotlin?
Can I use push() or pop() on keyB? Thank you.

Comment: If you declare `keyB` as a list/queue, you can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a mutable List for the second key:

```
object {
  val keyA = "ValueA"
  val keyB = mutableListOf("a", "b", "c")
}
```

Comment: Is it will be compiled to js array?  I need use the object on Vue.js

Comment: A list is a custom object in js. You need to convert the list to an array. `List.toTypedArray()`

Comment: @pixix4 "a custom object" really? Any source for that?

Comment: @JonasW. You can test it with `val list = mutableListOf(1, 2, 3, 4)`. `console.log(list)` prints `{ "modCount": 0, "array_hd7ov6$_0": [1, 2, 3, 4] }`. And `console.log(list.toTypedArray())` prints `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

Comment: @pixix4 weird design decision.

Answer (score 2):

It should be something like this.

```
val adHoc = object {
    var keyA: String = "ValueA"
    var keyB: Array<String> = arrayOf("a", "b", "c")
}
print(adHoc.keyA)
print(adHoc.keyB)
```